# unsure how to rotate object in opengl es 2

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am unsure on how to rotate my object.  Currently I have a quad and I want to be able to view it at a sort of 45 degree angle,  I have set up my model view projection matrix.  I know I should do this in the shader instead of in the actual code, I will change that later, but here is some code.

```
    bool bRotate = PVRShellGet(prefIsRotated) && PVRShellGet(prefFullScreen);
p_Matrix = PVRTMat4::PerspectiveFovRH(PVRT_PI / 6, (float) PVRShellGet(prefWidth) / (float) PVRShellGet(prefHeight), 4.0f, 1000.0f, PVRTMat4::OGL, bRotate);
PVRTVec3 view_From(2, 2, 0);
v_Matrix = PVRTMat4::LookAtRH(view_From, view_At, view_Up) * PVRTMat4::RotationX(45);
cam_Pos = view_From;

PVRTMat4 modelView, world, mMVP;
world = PVRTMat4::Identity();
modelView = v_Matrix * world;
mMVP = p_Matrix * modelView;

if(PVRShellGet(prefIsRotated) && PVRShellGet(prefFullScreen)) // If the screen is rotated
    mMVP = PVRTMat4::RotationZ(-1.57f);

/*
    Pass this matrix to the shader.
    The .m field of a PVRTMat4 contains the array of float used to
    communicate with OpenGL ES.
*/
glUniformMatrix4fv(m_ShaderProgram.auiLoc[eMVPMatrix], 1, GL_FALSE, mMVP.ptr());
```

I have tried rotating the mMVP matrix however it has no effect. and have also tried rotating the modelview and v_matrix(view matrix).  I used a function given by the SDK called PVRTMat4::RotationX(45);

Answer (score 0):

you can use the PVRTMat4::scale(fx,fy,fz) function to get a 44 matrix of the rotation u need. set the fx=45 and fy=0 and fz=0. then multiply the matrix returned to the mMVP matrix.